# Having trouble averaging arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to average the negative numbers in the list and average the positive numbers in the list as well as the average of the whole list. This is what i have so far I know it is not much but i'm not sure what my next step should be...

//This will read in a list of n values, where n is not known ahead of time. The number of values read into the array will be saved in n.

```
vector<int> readList()
{
std::vector<int> result;

ifstream inFile;

inFile.open("setA.txt");

for (int x; inFile >> x; )
{
    result.push_back(x);
}

return result;
}
```

//array is a one-dimensional array of integers and n is the number of elements in that array that contain valid data values. Both of these are input parameters to the function. The function must calculate 1) the average of the n integers in array, storing the result in ave; 2) the average of the positive numbers (> 0), storing the result in avePos, and 3) the average of the negative numbers (< 0), storing the result in aveNeg.

```
void avgs (std::vector<int> &array, int &ave, int &avePos, int &aveNeg)
{
     int sum = 0, pos_sum = 0, neg_sum = 0, pos_count = 0, neg_count = 0;
for (auto i : array)
{
    sum += i;
    if (i > 0) { pos_sum += i; ++pos_count; }
    if (i < 0) { neg_sum += i; ++neg_count; }
}

if(pos_sum) avePos = pos_sum / pos_count;
if(neg_sum) aveNeg = neg_sum / neg_count;
}
```

Comment: This is my new edit if you guys could recommend anything (the bottom part)

Comment: By the way I must use those perimeters in my functions

Comment: I edited my question, sorry guys for making other posts.

Comment: Come on man.  You can't expect us to do *everything* for you.  At some point in your programming career, you're going to have to think for yourself.  If you have a sum and a count, and you can't figure out how to get an average, you need to take a math class.  If you do know how to find the average, but can't figure out how to express that calculation in C++, then you need to read the first few chapters of [a C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I know how to get an average, i'm just confuse of how to get an average by only averaging the negatives and the positives. @BenjaminLindley

Comment: But you had the sum of the positives, and the count of the positives from my answer.  You also had the sum and count of the negatives, and the total sum and count.  Then you asked another question because you were doing the calculation wrong.  So what problem are you still having?

Comment: i'm not sure how to use the count_if in the for loop so i could get the averages.@BenjaminLindley

Comment: Why do you think you need `count_if`?  What do you think `pos_count` and `neg_count` are for?

Comment: Never mind I see what you mean. In that case do I get rid of the if(pos_sum) and if(neg_sum)? Please help, i'm sorry if I sound dumb but I am a beginner.@BenjaminLindley

Comment: Well, you need to check if `pos_count` and `neg_count` are zero, in order to prevent dividing by zero.  But your test works too, because if `pos_sum` is zero, so is `pos_count` (because the sum of zero positive integers is zero), and the same thing for the negative side.

Answer (score 3):

You could make 3 seperate calls to `accumulate` with custom summing functors.  Or you could use one call to `accumulate` with a very ugly summing functor. But a simple for loop which does all three at once would be better here, both for readability, and efficiency.

```
int sum = 0, pos_sum = 0, neg_sum = 0, pos_count = 0, neg_count = 0;
for (auto i : array)
{
    sum += i;
    if (i > 0) { pos_sum += i; ++pos_count; }
    if (i < 0) { neg_sum += i; ++neg_count; }
}
```

Make sure to check for zero on the `pos_count` and the `neg_count` before dividing.

Comment: The same could be with one std::accumulate.

Comment: And you would need to use `count_if` twice to get the number of positive and negative numbers to do the average.

Comment: @ZacHowland: Or you could just integrate that into the for loop, but thanks for reminding me.

Comment: No problem.  The only other issue is that these are all integers, so doing the division without casting (to get the average) would give truncated results.

Comment: @ZacHowland: Yes, but that seems to be what the OP wants, since he made the `ave`, `avePos` and `aveNeg` parameters integers.

Comment: Agreed ... though I think that is actually a problem with his requirements.

Comment: How could I change the parameters of this functions to meet my requirements (parameters in my function)

Comment: @user3003912: No changes necessary.  This gives you the sums and the counts.  Surely you can figure out the rest, right?  I didn't figure it was necessary to write your entire function.

Comment: I'm sorry it was a misunderstanding, thank you so much @BenjaminLindley

Answer (score 1):

```
ave = sum/array.size();
```

That will do integer division.  The average is very likely going to be a floating point value, so you need to cast first:

```
float ave = static_cast<float>(sum) / array.size();
```

To do the other averages, you'll want to sum up only the positive and negative values, respectively, and then divide by the number of positive and negative numbers, respectively.

Just to show it can be done:

```
void averages(const std::vector<int>& vec, double& overall_average, double& positive_average, double& negative_average)
{
    std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int> sums_and_counts = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::make_tuple(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), [](std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int> t, int i)
    {
        std::get<0>(t) += i;
        std::get<1>(t) += 1;
        if (i < 0)
        {
            std::get<2>(t) += i;
            std::get<3>(t) += 1;
        }

        if (i > 0)
        {
            std::get<4>(t) += i;
            std::get<5>(t) += 1;
        }
        return t;
    });

    overall_average = positive_average = negative_average = 0.0;
    if (std::get<1>(sums_and_counts))
    {
        overall_average = static_cast<double>(std::get<0>(sums_and_counts)) / std::get<1>(sums_and_counts);
    }

    if (std::get<3>(sums_and_counts))
    {
        negative_average = static_cast<double>(std::get<2>(sums_and_counts)) / std::get<3>(sums_and_counts);
    }

    if (std::get<5>(sums_and_counts))
    {
        positive_average = static_cast<double>(std::get<4>(sums_and_counts)) / std::get<5>(sums_and_counts);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's the ugly functor I referred to in my answer :) +1.  But if you want to make it slightly more readable, you could define some function local constants with appropriate names for 0 through 5.

Comment: I didn't want to make it too easy to read ;)  I actually toyed with the idea of returning a `tuple<double, double, double>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too lazy to test it, but I think this will work:

```
float avePos = static_cast<float>(accumulate(array.begin(), array.end(), 
                                   [](int sum, int x]->int
                                   {
                                      return sum + max(x, 0);
                                   }) / static_cast<float>(array.size());

float aveNeg = static_cast<float>(accumulate(array.begin(), array.end(), 
                                   [](int sum, int x]->int
                                   {
                                      return sum + min(x, 0);
                                   }) / static_cast<float>(array.size());
```

Comment: No, it won't work as is.  Either the number of positive numbers, or the number of negative numbers, or both, is going to be less than `array.size()`.  But in both cases, you are still dividing by `array.size()`, giving lower absolute value results.

Comment: [Benjamin Lindley](http://stackoverflow.com/users/440119/benjamin-lindley), I was so eager to show off that I knew how to do lamba functions that I forgot basic math.

Answer (score 0):

First off all you should count how many there are positive and negative elements in array.

You could use the same std::accumulate algorithm. For example

```
std::pair<int, int> count = std::accumulate( array.begin(), array.end(), std::make_pair( 0, 0 ),
                                             []( std::pair<int, int> p, int x )
                                             {
                                                 return ( p.first += x < 0, p.second += x > 0, p );
                                             } );
```

Then you can use the range-based for statement to get corresponding sums:

```
ave = aveNeg = avePos = 0;
for ( int x : array )
{
    ave += x;
    if ( x < 0 ) aveNeg += x;
    if ( 0 < x ) avePos += x;
}

if ( !array.empty() ) ave /= ( int )array.size();
if ( count.first ) aveNeg /= count.first;
if ( count.second ) avePos /= count.second;
```

Comment: Or `std::make_tuple` to give you all the values you would need to do the math.

Answer (score 0):

I think answer given by Benjamin Lindley is OK, but be careful with using int type for sum variable. It could easily overflow depending on your input values. Maybe use 64 bit integer if you are using 32 bit int, or use double. It all depends on what is the expected range of input values.